# BASH: asterisk as an argument

Tags: bash, shell, variable-expansion

I wrote a little BASH script that takes a simple config and grabs pre-configured 3rd party repositories, and downloads certain packages from them.

The problem I am currently having is that when I use an asterisk inside the config, it takes whatever directory I am in when executing the script, and expands all the files in my directory as arguments.  I understand the difference between single quotes and double quotes, but it seems like no matter what I do, I can't get it to work.  Maybe someone could give me a hand on this one.  Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIGS="/opt/configs/repos/.repos/configs"
REPOS="/opt/configs/repos"
MASTER_REPO=extras
SYNCAPPS=(mysql)

for APP in ${SYNCAPPS[@]};do
    . $CONFIGS/$APP
    echo "$APP"
    for RELEASE in {5..6};do
        if [ $RELEASE == "5" ];then
            for ARCH in {x86_64,i386};do
                CMD="yumdownloader --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=$UPSTREAM-$RELEASE-$ARCH -c $REPOS/.repos/$UPSTREAM-$RELEASE.repo --destdir=$REPOS/$MASTER_REPO/$RELEASE/$GEN_NAME/ $PACKAGES"
                $CMD
                echo ${CMD}
            done
        elif [ $RELEASE == "6" ];then
            for ARCH in {x86_64,i386};do
                                CMD="yumdownloader --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=$UPSTREAM-$RELEASE-$ARCH -c $REPOS/.repos/$UPSTREAM-$RELEASE.repo --destdir=$REPOS/$MASTER_REPO/$RELEASE/$GEN_NAME/ $PACKAGES"
                $CMD
                echo ${CMD}
                        done
        fi
    done
done
```

Sample Config (/opt/configs/repos/.repos/configs/mysql:

```
GEN_NAME=MySQL
UPSTREAM=mysql
PACKAGES=*
```

I have no issues with the download of the packages when the `PACKAGES` option is set to anything other than `*`, so I won't post any of the repo config (since I know the repos work).

My current directory I'm running this from:

```
# ls
mysql  salt  sysutils  zabbix
```

When I run the script:

```
# ./myscript.sh
mysql
yumdownloader --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=mysql-5-x86_64 -c /opt/data/build/repos/.repos/mysql-5.repo --destdir=/opt/data/build/repos/extras/5/MySQL/ mysql salt sysutils zabbix
yumdownloader --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=mysql-5-i386 -c /opt/data/build/repos/.repos/mysql-5.repo --destdir=/opt/data/build/repos/extras/5/MySQL/ mysql salt sysutils zabbix
yumdownloader --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=mysql-6-x86_64 -c /opt/data/build/repos/.repos/mysql-6.repo --destdir=/opt/data/build/repos/extras/6/MySQL/ mysql salt sysutils zabbix
yumdownloader --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=mysql-6-i386 -c /opt/data/build/repos/.repos/mysql-6.repo --destdir=/opt/data/build/repos/extras/6/MySQL/ mysql salt sysutils zabbix
```

What I want the output to be is:

```
mysql
yumdownloader --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=mysql-5-x86_64 -c /opt/data/build/repos/.repos/mysql-5.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/5/MySQL/ *
yumdownloader --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=mysql-5-i386 -c /opt/data/build/repos/.repos/mysql-5.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/5/MySQL/ *
yumdownloader --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=mysql-6-x86_64 -c /opt/data/build/repos/.repos/mysql-6.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/6/MySQL/ *
yumdownloader --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=mysql-6-i386 -c /opt/data/build/repos/.repos/mysql-6.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/6/MySQL/ *
```

The debug output for this run is here:

```
mysql
+ for RELEASE in '{5..6}'
+ '[' 5 == 5 ']'
+ for ARCH in '{x86_64,i386}'
+ CMD='yumdownloader --disablerepo='\''*'\'' --enablerepo=mysql-5-x86_64 -c /opt/configs/repos/.repos/mysql-5.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/5/MySQL/ *'
+ echo yumdownloader '--disablerepo='\''*'\''' --enablerepo=mysql-5-x86_64 -c /opt/configs/repos/.repos/mysql-5.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/5/MySQL/ mysql salt sysutils zabbix
yumdownloader --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=mysql-5-x86_64 -c /opt/configs/repos/.repos/mysql-5.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/5/MySQL/ mysql salt sysutils zabbix
+ for ARCH in '{x86_64,i386}'
+ CMD='yumdownloader --disablerepo='\''*'\'' --enablerepo=mysql-5-i386 -c /opt/configs/repos/.repos/mysql-5.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/5/MySQL/ *'
+ echo yumdownloader '--disablerepo='\''*'\''' --enablerepo=mysql-5-i386 -c /opt/configs/repos/.repos/mysql-5.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/5/MySQL/ mysql salt sysutils zabbix
yumdownloader --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=mysql-5-i386 -c /opt/configs/repos/.repos/mysql-5.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/5/MySQL/ mysql salt sysutils zabbix
+ for RELEASE in '{5..6}'
+ '[' 6 == 5 ']'
+ '[' 6 == 6 ']'
+ for ARCH in '{x86_64,i386}'
+ CMD='yumdownloader --disablerepo='\''*'\'' --enablerepo=mysql-6-x86_64 -c /opt/configs/repos/.repos/mysql-6.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/6/MySQL/ *'
+ echo yumdownloader '--disablerepo='\''*'\''' --enablerepo=mysql-6-x86_64 -c /opt/configs/repos/.repos/mysql-6.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/6/MySQL/ mysql salt sysutils zabbix
yumdownloader --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=mysql-6-x86_64 -c /opt/configs/repos/.repos/mysql-6.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/6/MySQL/ mysql salt sysutils zabbix
+ for ARCH in '{x86_64,i386}'
+ CMD='yumdownloader --disablerepo='\''*'\'' --enablerepo=mysql-6-i386 -c /opt/configs/repos/.repos/mysql-6.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/6/MySQL/ *'
+ echo yumdownloader '--disablerepo='\''*'\''' --enablerepo=mysql-6-i386 -c /opt/configs/repos/.repos/mysql-6.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/6/MySQL/ mysql salt sysutils zabbix
yumdownloader --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=mysql-6-i386 -c /opt/configs/repos/.repos/mysql-6.repo --destdir=/opt/configs/repos/extras/6/MySQL/ mysql salt sysutils zabbix
```

Thanks in advance - this has really thrown me for a loop...

Comment: It's spelled asterisk.

Comment: Read this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to embed a full command into a single variable is rarely a good idea. At the very least, separate the arguments into an array, and specify the command name by itself. Also, the `if` statement inside your `RELEASE` loop seems unnecessary, because the only difference between the two branches is the value of `RELEASE`.

```
CONFIGS="/opt/configs/repos/.repos/configs"
REPOS="/opt/configs/repos"
MASTER_REPO=extras
SYNCAPPS=(mysql)

for APP in "${SYNCAPPS[@]}"; do
    . "$CONFIGS/$APP"
    echo "$APP"
    for RELEASE in 5 6; do
        for ARCH in x86_64 i386; do
            arguments=( "--disablerepo=*"
                        "--enablerepo=$UPSTREAM-$RELEASE-$ARCH"
                        "-c"
                        "$REPOS/.repos/$UPSTREAM-$RELEASE.repo"
                        "--"
                        "destdir=$REPOS/$MASTR_REPO/$RELEASE/$GEN_NAME/"
                        "$PACKAGES"
                       )
            echo "yumdownloader ${arguments[@]}"
            yumdownloader "${arguments[@]}"
        done
    done
done
```

This ensures that the value of `PACKAGES` (and all the parameters, really) remains properly quoted wherever used.

Comment: in regards to you commend on the `if` statement; this is just initial stage of the script.  I have release specific items that will be going into it that I will need the `if` statement for.

Comment: +1 for the fundamental solution; perhaps say "into a variable containing a single string" - as opposed to an _array_ variable; (they're both _single_ variables).

Comment: @mklement0 True; in this case, a simple command can still be included in a single array and executed with `"${CMD[@]}"`. But as soon as you try anything more complex--`FOO=bar cmdname arg1`, `cmd1 | cmd2`, etc.--you're back to the problem of a single variable being insufficient. Best to stick with storing arguments only in an array, and leaving command names and higher syntax either hard-coded or wrapped in functions.

Comment: Whew: you caught that while I could still edit the comment :)

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  When I tried using this solution (awesome solution by the way; very well thought out, yet simple), it ended up  screwing up my regular repos, almost like I couldn't  have one (just asterisks) or the other (multiple items listed in a variable), so what I ended up doing in my config was setting the variable as an array list (e.g. `PACKAGES=(htop iftop cdpr)`) rather than `PACKAGES="htop iftop cdpr"`.  When doing this, it satisfied both asterisks and itemized lists, while still being able to use this elegant solution.  thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In your script instead of:

```
echo ${CMD}
```

You need to use:

```
echo "${CMD}"
```

To avoid shell expanding `*`.

When `*` is printed unquoted it expands to files and directories present in current directory.